# After Using bwlabel in MATLAB,Can I change the labels of the connected components?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matlab-figure

There are some white portions in a black object.

I need to cover up the all the white portions in the object with its neighboring black.

The bwlabel function labels the black part as '2' and white part as '1'.

can i somehow change the labels of the required object and cover the white portion with black.

I have isolated the objects individually using the following code:

```
 a=imread('3.jpg');
 figure(),imshow(a),title('Original image');

 b=im2bw(a, graythresh(a));
 figure(),imshow(b),title('Grayscale image');

 [c,num]=bwlabel(b);
 figure(),imshow(c),title('labelled image');

 for i=1:1:num
  figure(),imshow(c==i),title('OBJECT');
 end
```

What can i do further ?
Or is there any other way to achieve the same?

Answer (score 0):

Can you do

Find the indices of the white area

```
ind_white = find(c==1);
```

Replace the white area with zeros

```
b(ind_white) = 0;
```

or you can change the label of the white object to that of the black

```
c(ind) = 2;
```